# Quiz night - problem

Tags: word-problem

A group of 11 friends head to the pub on quiz night. The maximum team size allowed is 3 and nobody wants to compete solo! In how many different groupings can the friends enter into the quiz?

Any ideas on how to do this??

Comment: This question is part of the [Newcastle University Senior Challenge '17](http://www.ncl.ac.uk/maths/outreach/teachers/challenge/) (question 5 _Quiz Night Quandry_ of [this pdf](http://www.ncl.ac.uk/media/wwwnclacuk/mathematicsandstatistics/files/mathschallenge2017/Newcastle%20Senior%20Maths%20Challenge%202017.pdf)). The stated due date for entries is 10 March 2017, and this question will remain locked with answers temporarily deleted until after this date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint -

We have 2 cases.

Case 1 - Group sizes are 3, 3, 3, 2.

Case 2 - Group sizes are 2, 2, 2, 2, 3.

Hope you can proceed further.

Comment: Does this mean that there're only two groupings?